# почему результат функции не записывается в input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="num1" />

<div id="operator_btns">
  <button id="plus" class="operator" onclick="func('+')">+</button>
  <button id="minus" class="operator" onclick="func('-')">-</button>
  <button id="times" class="operator" onclick="func('*')">x</button>
  <button id="divide" class="operator" onclick="func('/')">:</button>
</div>

<input id="num2" />

<input id="result">
<script>
    
  function func(op) {
    var result;
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    switch (op) {
      case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
      case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
      case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
      case '/':
        if (num2) {
          result = num1 / num2;
        } else {
          result = 'бесконечность';
        }
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: потому что у `input` нет `innerHTML` у него есть `value`

Comment: Result у вас инпут. Значит значения надо добавлять не в innerHTML, а в value.

Comment: всем большое спасибо!